# How to get MSE of ARIMA model in SAS?

Tags: statistics, sas

I am comparing two models, one with exponential smoothing and one with ARIMA.

For this specific assignment, it's enough that I compare the MSE of the two models.

So how do I compute the MSE of the ARIMA procedure?

This is the last assignment on this grueling course, help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I'm not sure it is available in ARIMA.  If you are only fitting an AR model, then you could use PROC AUTOREG which will give you an MSE value.  Otherwise, you will have to take the output from ARIMA and calculate it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

`proc arima` does not specifically output the MSE, but `proc model` does. You can recreate the ARIMA model using `proc model` and the [`%AR` and `%MA` macros.](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/etsug/60372/HTML/default/viewer.htm#etsug_model_sect054.htm)

```
proc model data=have;
    endo y;
    id date;

    y = mu;
    %AR(AR, 1, y, m=ML);
    %MA(MA, 1, y, m=ML);

    fit y;
run;
```

This specifies an ML-estimated ARMA(1,0,1) model with an intercept, `mu`.

`proc model` will then output the MSE of your model. Note that `%MA` *must* come after `%AR`, and both the `%AR` and `%MA` macros *must* come after the equation.

If you need a more complicated lag structure, you can specify additional options in either macro:

`%AR(AR, 3, y, 1 3, M=ML)`

This creates ML-estimated AR variables of order 3 whose variable prefix is `AR` using a subset of lags 1 and 3.

Here is an example of output using `sashelp.air` with the `%AR` macro:

[image]
Note that any differencing must be performed in a data step before entering `proc model`.