# How can I get the MSE from my ARIMA model in SAS?

Tags: sas, statistics, time-series, arima

The code I am using is as follows:

```
 ods html close;
    ods html;
    data petrol2;
    infile 'M:\Dissertation\Raw Data\split2forecast.csv' delimiter=',';
    input date $ price;
    run;
    proc arima data=petrol2;
    identify var=price(1);
    estimate p=2 q=1 method=ml;
    forecast lead=3;
    run;
```

I need to calculate the MSE and Bias from my time series but cannot figure out what to do, help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

MSE can be calculated using PROC MODEL:

[How to get MSE of ARIMA model in SAS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991749/how-to-get-mse-of-arima-model-in-sas)

MSE has a relationship with bias that you can calculate. MSE is exactly equal to:

[image: MSE-Bias relationship]

Using the output from PROC MODEL and the MSE-Bias relationship, you can calculate the bias of your estimators.